# Bulk insert on multi-column unique constraint Django

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

Suppose we have a model

```
from django.db import models

class Concept(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('a', 'b'),
                name='first_two_constraint'),
        ]
```

I want to execute `bulk_create` on this model such that, on a unique constraint violation of 'first_two_constraint', an update would be performed.

For sqlite3, the features
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/sqlite3/features.py#L44
forces that `unique_fields` be passed to the `bulk_create` function. However, it's non-obvious to me what that should be.
https://github.com/django/django/blob/829f4d1448f7b40238b47592fc17061bf77b0f23/django/db/models/query.py#L701

I tried the constraint's name, however that failed. Tracing, that occurs since this list of `unique_fields` is specifically the field names, and there wouldn't be a field name for a constraint .
https://github.com/django/django/blob/829f4d1448f7b40238b47592fc17061bf77b0f23/django/db/models/query.py#L768

As a result, I'm at a loss of how to approach this issue.

Based off of the sqlite3 documentation, https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html sub-heading 'REPLACE', the functionality should be possible as, even if it's multiple columns, the violation would still be a unique constraint violation "When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs..."

Does anyone have any insight as to how to deal with multiple column constraints with the `bulk_create` function or confirmation that the only approach to this is with raw SQL?

I don't believe it's to have `unique_fields=('a', 'b')` as that would be representative of two separate column constraints, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. My model fields allowed me to use this hacky solution. It worked.

```
class Concept(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    _a_b = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Not that this won't be helpful when doing a bulk_create so you will 
        # have to set this value when creating the bulk_create objects
        self._a_b = f"{self.a}{self.b}"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('a', 'b'),name='a_b_constraint'),
        ]

Concept.objects.bulk_create(
    concepts, # make sure to create _a_b in the loop that create this
    update_conflicts=True,
    update_fields=('c','d',),
    unique_fields=('_a_b',)
)
```