# Combined unique_field in bulk_create in without checking PK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, bulkinsert

I am trying to import data from multiple API's and there is a chance of duplicates. I am trying to bulk-create without duplication. All API sources do not provide me with a unique identifier. I am wondering what the best way to handle this situation is. What I have tried is as follows:

```
 if 'rounds' in response:
    print('=== Syncing Rounds ===')
    rounds = response.get('rounds')
    objs = [
        Round(
            name         = item.get('name'),
            season       = Season.objects.get(id = item.get('seasonId')),
            competition  = Competition.objects.get(id = item.get('competitionId')),
            round_number = item.get('roundNumber'),
        )
        for item in rounds
    ]
    Round.objects.bulk_create(
        objs,update_conflicts=True, 
        update_fields=['name','season','competition','round_number'],
        unique_fields=['id'])
```

I tried setting `ignore_conflicts = True` but that approach didn't help me.

The round numbers range from 1-30 and the season is the year. In the given situation, I cannot make one field unique such as round number, season, or competition. It has to look for all three. For example There can be only one row for Round 1, 2023, for competition 112. This entire combination is unique.

**Goal**

**The end goal is to either ensure no duplicate entries or update existing rows.**

One hack (as said by OP) solution is [Bulk insert on multi-column unique constraint Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079183/bulk-insert-on-multi-column-unique-constraint-django)

---Update---
`Round Model`

```
class Round (models.Model):
name         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
round_number = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
season       = models.ForeignKey(Season,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
competition  = models.ForeignKey(Competition,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
start        = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
end          = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
tries        = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
points       = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['round_number','season','competition'], 
            name='unique_round')
```

I have tried using constraints but no dice

Comment: Please sharre the given model. It is also not clear to me what you aim to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your `unique_field` can not be `id`, since that is one that is not determined by the object. The `unique_field` decides for which fields there should at least be one value that is different in order to update. In case the `season`, `competition_id`, and `round_number` are the same, we can for example update the `name`.

Your view also is not very efficient. Yes, the [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) will save a lot of insert queries, but the main bottleneck is retrieving all competitions, etc. That is *not* necessary. If we know for sure the objects exist, we can work with:

```
if 'rounds' in response:
    objs = [
        Round(
            name=item['name'],
            season_id=item['seasonId'],
            competition_id=item['competitionId'],
            round_number=item['roundNumber'],
        )
        for item in response['rounds']
    ]
    Round.objects.bulk_create(
        objs,
        update_conflicts=True,
        update_fields=['name'],
        unique_fields=['season_id', 'competition_id', 'round_number'],
    )
```